# Is it possible to merge from one branch to another in git with only certain files?

Tags: git, merge

Let's say I have two branches

- A
- B

I want to merge the changes in `A` to `B`. However, `A` has some files that I changed as well as some files that someone else changed. For example, in `A`, there are 2 files that changed.

- path/to/JavaFile1.java (I changed this file)
- path/to/another/JavaFile2.java (another user changed this file)

On merging from `A` to `B`, I find that there are conflicts with the file that someone else changed (in the running example, `JavaFile2.java`). Now, I want the merge to proceed so as to

- "ignore" or "skip" the file that was changed by someone else (I don't know how to resolve that conflict)
- I want the merge to be such that when someone else merges, they too will also have to deal with the conflict and decide what to do.

I am not sure if a resolution of using `mine` or `theirs` is appropriate, because on the next merge, it might never consider the conflict again (git will mark the conflicts as resolved in future merges).

I suppose I can cherry-pick too, but on our team, we have a policy to `merge` forward (e.g. from `A` to `B`) and cherry-pick backwards (e.g. from `B` to `A`).

Is it possible to do as I stated? We also have a policy that a developer must merge their own commits, but, unfortunately, this developer is not available for the next two weeks (vacation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the conceptually easiest way to deal with this would be to perform the merge and then reset the file in question to the commit in `B` which was at the `HEAD` of that branch before the merge.

The command you would use to reset the file modified by another user is:

```
git checkout <SHA-1> path/to/another/JavaFile2.java
```

where `<SHA-1>` is the hash of the most recent commit on `B` before you did the merge (i.e. the version you want to keep).

If there is a merge conflict in this file during the merge, then you can reset it using the above command and commit.  If the merge completes without a conflict, then you can still run the above command, and you can amend the merge commit:

```
git add path/to/another/JavaFile2.java
git commit --amend
```

Comment: Can I do `git checkout HEAD path/to/another/JavaFile2.java` instead? With this approach, if someone tries to merge from `A` to `B`, git will still force the user to resolve the second file right (`JavaFile2.java`)?

Comment: @JaneWayne If the merge completes automatically with a commit, then `HEAD` will be pointing to that new commit and `git checkout HEAD JavaFile2.java` will do nothing.